# Why only one thread works?

Tags: c, multithreading

I created this program which consists in one thread adding 1 when the value is equal o less than 5 and one thread subtracting 1 when the value is higher than 5.
The problem is that only one thread works and sometimes none of them work and I can't figure out now to resolve this problem.

There are 2 global variables:

```
int value=0;
pthread_mutex_t mux=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

This is the `sum` function:

```
void* sum(void* args){
  int exit;
  while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);
    if(value<=5){
      value=value+1;
    }
    printf("value: %d\n",value);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);
    sleep(1);
  }
  pthread_exit((void*)&exit);
}
```

This is the `sub` function:

```
void* sub(void* args){
  int exit;
  while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mux);
    if(value>5){
      value=value-1;
    }
    printf("value: %d\n",value);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux);
  }
  pthread_exit((void*)&exit);
}
```

And this is the `main` function:

```
int main(){

  pthread_t inc,dec;
  int status;

  if(pthread_create(&dec,NULL,sottrazione,NULL)){
    printf("Sub thread can't be created\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  if(pthread_create(&inc,NULL,somma,NULL)){
    printf("Sum thread can't be created\n");
    exit(-2);
  }
  if(pthread_join(inc,(void*)&status) && pthread_join(dec,(void*)&status)){
    printf("Join failed\n");
    exit(-3);
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Expected output should be:

```
value: 0
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
value: 4
value: 5
value: 6
value: 5
...
```

Comment: Your `sub` function keeps the lock held while sleeping.

Comment: Also, I think you want to move the work (the `printf`) into the `if`. If so, this would be a great scenario for using `cond_wait`.

Comment: I feel that you are trying to use sleep as a way of thread synchronization which is not a reliable way. Should always refrain from such practice. Also mutex can not help you in getting an ordered output all it does is protect your shared resource from race condition that is from parallel access.

Answer (score 0):

In above case `value` is a global variable and when `sub` is called it acquires the lock and not unlocking it. Even though *thread switching* is happening because of `sleep` but since *same mutex variable* is used in both `sub` and `sum` threads, when control moves to `sum` thread but `mux` is still locked so it won't enter into critical section of code and it comes back into previous(`sub`) thread.

To avoid this problem either you should take *two mutex variable* or use **condition variable**.

**Option-1 :**

```
pthread_mutex_t mux1=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mux2=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void* sum(void* args){
        int exit;
        while(1){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mux1);/* when it comes here, mux1 is still un-locked so it will lock & enters */
                if(value<=5){
                        printf("value_sum: %d\n",value);
                        value=value+1;
                }

                fflush(stdout);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux2);
                sleep(1);
        }
        pthread_exit((void*)&exit);
}
void* sub(void* args){
        int exit;
        while(1){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mux2); /* first lock the mux2 */
                if(value>5){
                        printf("value_sub: %d\n",value);
                        value=value-1;
                }

                fflush(stdout);
                sleep(1);/* because of this control moves to sum thread */
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mux1);
        }
        pthread_exit((void*)&exit);
}
```

**Option 2 :-** use **condition variable** concept.

```
int pthread_cond_wait(pthread_con_t *cond,pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```